# How to use generalized object for 2 different classes?

Tags: java, object, components, javabeans

I have 2 component classes

1. OrderDetailsSite1.java
2. OrderDetailsSite2.java

I have one bean class where I'm storing the Shopping cart details

- Product Name
- Quantity
- Unit Price
- Subtotal

Now I have to create one common method where I have to pass the Component class Object and compare the values with, bean class data.

Code trial :

```
public void validateProductDetails(Object obj) {

    OrderDetailBean bean = (OrderDetailBean) ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getObject("order_details");
    OrderDetailsSite1 comp=null;

    if (obj instanceof OrderDetailsSite1) {

        comp = (OrderDetailsSite1) obj;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bean.getProductName().size(); i++) {

        assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductName().getText(), bean.getProductName().get(i));
        assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductQuantity().getText(), bean.getProductQuantity().get(i));
        assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductUnitPrice().getText(), bean.getProductUnitprice().get(i));
        assertResult(comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductSubtotal().getText(), bean.getProductSubtotal().get(i));
    }

}
```

The code what i have done for component 1 but for component 2 do i need to repeat the same code ? or is there any provision to do the same in efficient way

**EDITED**

I'm working with selenium and I have created same variable and method name in both class but the locators for both are different. Is is possible to do the same using super class concept ?

**`OrderDetailsSite1.java`**

```
@FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.name")
private QAFWebElement productName;

@FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.quantity")
private QAFWebElement productQuantity;

@FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.price")
private QAFWebElement productUnitPrice;

@FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.subtotal")
private QAFWebElement productSubtotal;
```

**`OrderDetailsSite2.java`**

```
@FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.name")
private QAFWebElement productName;

@FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.uprice")
private QAFWebElement productUnitPrice;

@FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.quantity")
private QAFWebElement productQuantity;

@FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.subtotal")
private QAFWebElement productSubtotal;
```

method name in both classes are same.

Comment: Unless `OrderDetailsSite1` and `OrderDetailsSite2` have a common superclass offering access to those properties, there is little you can do but duplicate code.

Comment: You could extract your code to a method in a static service/util class if the duplicated code bothers you that much. Other than that I only see the superclass solution as @AndyTurner mentioned.

Comment: @AndyTurner, i have edited the question. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Make Components interface and implement it component classes

```
interface Components{
...// declare all methods of your components like getProductList() etc
...
}

public void validateProductDetails(Components comp) {

OrderDetailBean bean = (OrderDetailBean) ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getObject("order_details");

for (int i = 0; i < bean.getProductName().size(); i++) {

    assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductName().getText(), bean.getProductName().get(i));
    assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductQuantity().getText(), bean.getProductQuantity().get(i));
    assertResult( comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductUnitPrice().getText(), bean.getProductUnitprice().get(i));
    assertResult(comp.getProductList().get(i).getProductSubtotal().getText(), bean.getProductSubtotal().get(i));
}

}
```

Comment: You can't check `instanceof T`. Wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Now `comp` is always null, so you'd get a NPE whenever `bean.getProductName().size() > 0`.

Comment: You can't invoke `getProductList()` on a `T`, because it's an unbounded type variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for suggestions, Now i think, I fixed all errors

Comment: There is no need to use generics if you just use `T comp`. `Components comp` works identically.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**, from updated question

From your code above, I would use this approach.

Create an interface that will provide common api for your order detail sites.

```
public interface class OrderDetailsComponent{
    private QAFWebElement productQuantity;
    private QAFWebElement productQuantity;
    private QAFWebElement productUnitPrice;
    private QAFWebElement productSubtotal;
}
```

Both your classes should implement your interface

```
public class OrderDetailsSite1 implements OrderDetailsComponent{
    @FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.name")
    private QAFWebElement productName;

    @FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.quantity")
    private QAFWebElement productQuantity;

    @FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.price")
    private QAFWebElement productUnitPrice;

    @FindBy(locator = "magento.ordered.item.subtotal")
    private QAFWebElement productSubtotal;
}

public class OrderDetailsSite2 implements OrderDetailsComponent {
    @FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.name")
    private QAFWebElement productName;

    @FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.uprice")
    private QAFWebElement productUnitPrice;

    @FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.quantity")
    private QAFWebElement productQuantity;

    @FindBy(locator = "order.detail.product.subtotal")
    private QAFWebElement productSubtotal;
}
```